# Full GC - Sun JVM frequency of run

Tags: java, jvm, jstat

In JDK 1.6 : I see that full GC has been run but the old generation and perm gen space is not used completely - question is as per my understanding FGC only runs when old gen or perm gen is full - I am not able to understand why it has run even though usage % is low?.

See output of jstat -gcutil below:

```
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 0.00  82.14  51.17  13.78  26.43    219   19.347     1    0.131   19.479

   S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 82.14   0.00   9.12  13.92  26.66    222   19.771     1    0.131   19.902

   S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 82.14   0.00  11.07   9.07  24.15    230   20.166     2    1.851   22.017
```

My min/max heap is 1024M and min and max permGen space is defined as 768M.

Comment: One possible reason could be RMI: " RMI forces periodic full collection. The frequency of these collections can be controlled with properties.java -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval  and
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval"  http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by placing the jvm opts : `XX:-DisableExplicitGC` .

Some code in some external jar file may have been explicitly calling `System.gc` resulting in such garbage collection behavior. Disabling these, resulted in the expected behavior of Garbage Collection running when 100% usage was about to be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Switch on the verbose gc to now exactly when the full gc has happend. Because jstat shows FGC events even for major/tenured collections

[For more info visit](http://tech-wikis.blogspot.com/2010/11/compare-jstat-vs-verbosegc-vs-visualvm.html).

Answer (score 0):

> FGC only runs when old gen or perm gen is full

It's not true. Read java reference paper [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)

Memory management in Java may surprise everyone. It takes many years to learn how to set JVM parameters for non-trivial applications.

> permGen space is defined as 768M.

Decrease it to 128M

Comment: Cannot decrease perm gen space - as our application consumes it heavily... are there any disadvantage to using a high value for it?

Comment: Why does you application consume perm gen heavily ? Do You use dom xml parser or compare many strings an call intern ?

Comment: From the pdf link you have quoted: "When the young generation fills up, a young generation collection (sometimes referred to as a minor collection) of just that generation is performed. When the old or permanent generation fills up, what is known as a full
collection (sometimes referred to as a major collection) is typically done" . What are those cases when the old/perm gen are not full and yet GC is done??.

Comment: Which app server do You use ?

Comment: You have problem with YG not PG or OG. Which collector do you use ?   Tomcat in this version is a museum.leaks. First of all decrease PG (it use only 25%)  or increase heap.